# Would a [nazis] tag be useful?

Tags: discussion, tags

I was answering [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/174862/what-was-the-first-work-involving-nazis-and-occult-magic) and thought that we have asked about the inclusion of [those wacky nazis](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ThoseWackyNazis) and inspiration derived from their intolerant ideology in science fiction and fantasy many times. A rapid search for the term throws 264 results.

I was going to create the tag but on second thought maybe such a tag is kind of controversial or not needed. What do you think? Would it be offensive to create such a tag? Can it be useful?

Edit: do you think a tag named [nazi-villains] is a good compromise in order to avoid possible problems but at the same time adress the issue?

Comment: I don't ussually ask for explanation of downvotes but since it might be relevant for concensus: can you please explain if your downvote means you are against the creation of the tag?

Answer (score 1):

When I asked that question, I noticed that there wasn't an extant [nazis] tag.  I thought about creating one, but decided against it; not for any good reason, but I just felt uncomfortable doing it.  However, a quick search does seem to show that there are enough questions about stories involving the Nazis to justify the tag.

In short, there are reasonable reasons to have the tag.  However, if it makes a significant number of people uncomfortable, I think we are fine doing without.

EDIT:  I went ahead and made the tag, then took a shower.  At present, the tag is only associated with my question that prompted this discussion, so if there turns out to be opposition to the tag, it can be removed.

Comment: Seems like we had the same feeling yet i think your question shows how it could be needed.

Comment: Hooray, now we can become a magnet site for neo-nazis looking for inspirational writings :-)

Comment: @Valorum do you really think that will be a problem? Can it be avoided by naming the tag differently? Maybe nazis-in-fiction or nazi-villains

Comment: @Valorum - No more than a hundred thousand academic sites that must be much higher in the search engine rankings. :)

Comment: You should really wait for proper community consensus before carrying out these actions.

Comment: @Edlothiad Why? Creating a new tag is an action which can easily be taken by a single user, and reversed by another single user if need be. As long as he isn't performing bulk or controversial actions (e.g. dozens of edits in one go, or engaging in edit wars) ... it's not necessary to ask meta before creating every new tag.

Comment: Well considering a meta was asked, (given the answerer themselves said they weren't sure) they should probably wait for community consensus rather than "Oh I wrote a meta answer, now it's fine" I can edit tag-wikis to whatever I like, doesn't mean I should change the animals tag to the excerpt I proposed in another meta even though I have 5 down-votes. Just because the privilege exists doesn't mean you can carry out the action without thought.

Answer (score -2):

### Let's create a [nazi-villains] tag

- **Why a category like nazis and the like is useful**

There is a significant number of questions/answers that deal with the subject, in a quick search 265 results.The question that prompted this question lacked any other useful tag to get a correct identification.

Some of these are story-identification that without this tag are not properly identified fo future searchs:

1. [Movie involving time-travelling Nazis](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/43737/movie-involving-time-travelling-nazis)
2. [Name of movie about little girl that moved to forest camp run by Nazis, with her mother](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/137398/name-of-movie-about-little-girl-that-moved-to-forest-camp-run-by-nazis-with-her)
3. [Identify a 90's Disney movie featuring spaceship "surprise" and futuristic Neo Nazis](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/18693/identify-a-90s-disney-movie-featuring-spaceship-surprise-and-futuristic-neo-n)

.

- **Can people be offended or attract unwanted attraction to the site?**

We are certainly not promoting this intolerant and murderous ideology, lots of history scholars do deal with the category and are not making an apologia of nazism.

As Adamant points in a comment, many scholar sites are higher in the search engine rankings.

But then again, the idea is not to make anyone feel uncomfortable while using this site.

.

- **How do we land in the safe side of this debate?**

Nazis are the villains of the story for obvious reasons. I have yet to find a work of fiction, a question or an answer where the nazis are not the villains.

If we take that into consideration a tag namesd [nazi-villains] can properly identify the questions and avoid making people uncomfortable.

Comment: I don't think the "villains" qualifier is necessary in the tag title. After all we dealing with *fictional* Nazis, so if there was ever a story (even if unlikely) where the Nazis are the heroes do we need to create a new tag with a "hero" qualifier?. We have other tags such as [tag:death-eaters] and [tag:smaug], while clearly villains do have this qualifier in tag title. If any *real* Nazis show and try to spread hate or other abusive behavior there are already mechanisms in place to handle that.

Comment: I agree that this seems excessive. I don't need a tag name to tell me that the Nazis are villainous. Their actions are quite enough for that. I can't see why someone would be upset by the presence of a [tag:nazi] tag, but not by the presence of questions about Nazis. History has Nazi Germany and Nazism tags, and apparently don't see the need for a Nazi Villains tag. While I do question whether we need this tag at all (it's just another Story ID meta tag), if we're going to have it "Nazi Villains" seems like the wrong name.

Comment: Calling it [nazi-villains] restricts it to works where the Nazis are the story antagonists--what about works that include Nazis as background characters, etc?

Comment: To be honest I would go without the villains, but I really think we need one tag for the situation and if people feel more comfortable with that tag I think it might be worth suggesting it.